# Does Apple rejects app which has react native webview and third party payments in it

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, in-app-purchase

We are making web application and using paypal and stripe as payment gatweys for upgrading plan in the web application, now we are trying to make an iOS app using react native webview and using same payment gatways in it.

I have read somewhere that apple reject third parties payment gateway for subscriptions so we are not trying it

So, please help us out because we are confused and not taking any step yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your APP contains virtual goods, you must add Apple Pay；

Answer (score 0):

Apple insists on using Apple Pay so they can, I think, have a percentage of the payments (20 or 30%).

If you offer a payment system other than Apple Pay, Apple may simply not validate the app on the stores.